# Unity 5 particle-deleting c# Script

Tags: c#, scripting, unity-game-engine

I was following a unity tutorial started on Unity 4 but I am on Unity 5, and when I try to use the script seen (https://youtu.be/vwUahWrY9Jg?t=1337) and I try to use it, it gives an error:

> Assets/Scripts/DestroyFinishedParticle.cs(18,17): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Destroy' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

this is the code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class DestroyFinishedParticle : MonoBehaviour {

    private ParticleSystem thisParticleSystem;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        thisParticleSystem = GetComponent<ParticleSystem>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update() {
        if (thisParticleSystem.isPlaying)
            return;

        Destroy (GameObject);
    }
}
```

It can be because C# code for unity changed from 4 to 5? what should I change? The problem seems to be in the `Update` method.

Comment: I've *never* used Unity, so I'll leave myself to comments here. According to http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Destroy.html `Destroy()` is a static method - try `Object.Destroy(GameObject);`

Comment: I've set that and didn't work, then set back the `destroy()` with Ctrl Z and just works. Sometimes I hate programming xD thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There are couple of issues with this code.

First, you didn't mention to what exactly is it attached too? I assume it attached to the Particle System.

Secondly, use "gameObject", not "GameObject", since GameObject is the name of the class.

Third, I believe there's a much more efficient way to destroy the gameObject without checking every frame whether the particles system has finished or not, maybe set a small timer? or invoke the function with time?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how your event is set up would depend on the approach to checking if the particles are running. If you can setup a collider to when you walk in, you can trigger an event to know the particles are on. Upon exiting the collider, the particles will shut off.

I'm not 100% on the syntax of return in C# but seems like it should go after you destroy your game object. I think return works in a similar fashion as the break in that aspect.(Especially since you don't seem to be returning any values anyway why do you need it?)